# German Magento Webshop Setup

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is anyone worked on such templating. My client does not wants Region/States on the customer address section any where on the shop but magento is having region is required in many forms. Is there any way to disable it or should i work with each form.

Please some one help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the forms there is no 'if' around the region/state entries whereas there is for things like 'salutation'. For this reason you may want to edit each form.

Comment: You mean, forms under onepage directory inside template or where you pointing. Please can you tell more specific.